# tomcat in docker container : java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: java, linux, docker, kubernetes, tomcat

I am using docker to run my java war application and when I run the container I got this exception **java.net.BindException: Address already in use** .

The container expose port 8085 (8080->8085/tcp)
I executed this command to run the docker container :

> docker run -p 8080:8085/tcp  -d --name=be-app  java-app-image:latest

this is screenshot of the error
[image]

I checked the opened ports inside the container
[image]

I cannot restart the tomcat inside the container because it will stop , I thought about changing the 8085 port in the server.xml file , but I think that I should change the exposed port also.
Is there any solution to avoid this exception ? ( java.net.BindException: Address already in use)

this is also what I am getting when I run command ps aux
[image]

Comment: Seems your only options are to run on a port that isn't in use or change the application that is using 8085 to another port. There is no way to bind two applications to one port, if that is what you're after.

Comment: exposing another port instead of 8085? or changing this port in server.xml file? @theherk

Comment: Since it's a Java exception, the exception must occur inside the container. It seems very strange that port 8085 should be taken inside the container. All ports should be available. It almost seems like you might be running 2 instances of Tomcat in the container?

Comment: @HansKilian 
I am running one instance  in tomcat , I am running catalina.sh start command .

Comment: @HansKilian 

I updated the question I added the output of ps command

Comment: You seem to have added a PNG file; commands like `ps` will output plain text.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the images with text (which can be much more easily read and searched for)?

Comment: Show us the Dockerfile, I‘ll assume that you are using a base image which starts Tomcat by itself.

Answer (score 2):

The `ps` shows *two* java processes, possibly running Tomcat.

Since they would be running with the same parameters, including ports, it seems expected the second process fails with

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Make sure to `docker stop` everything first, and check the status of `docker ps --all`

Comment: Hello , thank you for responding me. I stoped the container, and I builded also another image and I runned it with docker-compose . the same error occured , java.net.BindException: Address already in use.

Comment: @Y.hadj.younes Than it is possible your ENTRYPOINT step is running a script which launches the java process *twice*.